# withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Tags: swift, swift5

I am seeing a deprecation warning from xcode for using withUnsafeBytes. Below is the code snippet. Can anyone suggest the right way to use withUnsafeBytes without throwing the warning : withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead. I have tried few other links and solutions but nothing seems to be working.

```
var keyBytes = data.withUnsafeBytes {
            [UInt8](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: data.count))
}
```

Comment: If your intent is only convert `Data` to array of bytes all you need is `let bytes = Array(data)`. Note that `Data` conforms to `MutableCollection`, `RandomAccessCollection` and `RangeReplaceableCollection` since Swift 3

Comment: Array(data) did work thanks